# How to make a window floating on desktop?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, floating, method-group

I am trying to create a button to make a windows floating on the desktop using "topmost" but I can't assign a Boolean to the button, because it is a 
method group

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(this.TopMost)
            {
                this.TopMost = true;
                Button1_Click = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.TopMost = false;
                Button1_Click = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Button1_Click = true;` what are you trying to do with this again?

Comment: I'm trying to have 2 function for the button, if it's clicked, it makes the window float even if I focus on other windows, and if it's clicked again, it makes the window become normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually pretty short:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 TopMost = !TopMost;
}
```

You don't need to include `this` since you are already in the scope of your form and your if else logic can be shortened to `e = !e`.

```
Button1_Click
```

Is a method, you can't assign a value to it.

Comment: @TrungVũĐức you can accept my answer if it helped you, thanks